# Jenkins agent crashes with warning Failed to load DLL from static location

Tags: agent, jenkins-agent

I am running agent like following

java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://localhost:8080/computer/simat01/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret 850bab2a8bd0486e7db9365bd08d1801abc4ebbef9a449aa396fab682f53940e -noCertificateCheck.

It run successfully and  connected.

But after that it create problem like following.

WARNING: Failed to load DLL from static location
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Users\jojo.jenkins\cache\jars\ED\winp.x64.BFFE30B3B50581290B1866EF8D48C609.dll already loaded in another classloader
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2471)